# Async anonymous function: is then() necessary?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

See the following [code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/example/chrome_android.js):

```
'use strict';

const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('..');
const {Options} = require('../chrome');

(async function() {
  let driver;
  try {
    driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(new Options().androidChrome())
        .build();
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
  } finally {
    await driver && driver.quit();
  }
})().then(_ => console.log('SUCCESS'), err => console.error('ERROR: ' + err));
```

My question is: when will that `.then(_ ...` ever get called? The async function doesn't return anything; plus, it seems to catch all possible problems except at the very end, in that "finally". So... is the `.then(` there so that it will catch errors quitting the driver? Or is there more?

Comment: "The async function doesn't return anything" Wrong. async function returns a promise.

Comment: OK, fine. But it's a promise which, once resolved, is undefined. So, when would `console.error('ERROR: ' + err))` EVER get called?

Answer (score 1):

When you throw an error inside your function, then your error handler will be called.

```js
(async function() {
      throw 1;
    })()
    .then(_ => console.log('SUCCESS'), err => console.error('ERROR: ' + err))
```

Also, you don't need try-catch for full function block. That's what the second argument in your then will handle.

Comment: Alright but in the snippet I provided, will that  `console.error('ERROR: ' + err)` EVER get executed? If so, when?